# JavaScript Insert div every 100px of parent div

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to insert divs every 100px of parent div height?

```
<div id="parent">
     Text text text text text
     text text text text text
     text text text text text
  <div id="child"></div> //100px from top
     Text text text text text
     text text text text text
     text text text text text
  <div id="child"></div> //200px from top
     Text text text text text
     text text text text text
     text text text text text
</div>
```

Comment: same IDs........invalid. and i don't think such thing can be calculated.

Comment: Add to your css file: `.child{padding-top: 100px;}` and add to your divs the classes: `class="child"`

Comment: @NapkinHD would this css put the second div at top padding of 200.

Comment: @Jai Actually it should set the second div 100px underneath the first div, because there is noch css property like float. So the divs will be placed underneath with 100px padding.